# vim arrow keys inserting strange character in iterm2

Tags: iterm

vim escape & arrow keys are inserting strange character (the letter q in my case) but works perfectly if launched in a tmux session or with terminal.app

Someone having the same problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the Report Terminal Type to ansi or linux in my profile solved my problem.

When the terminal type of your sessions is set to one of those "xterm" types, iTerm handles the arrow keys, the home key, and the end key in a special way.

Comment: this worked for me after i restarted tmux/iterm2

Comment: yeah, but doing that screws with 256 color modes (e.g. solarized). there is an issue in iTerm2 to address this.